# Duplicating items in DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this code where I put data to the `DataTable` from where I show everything on `DataGridView`.
But when I look it contains information which supposed to be in file but its repeated twice. [image]

Code to retrieve data from mysql database:

```
MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter;
    DataSet DS0 = new DataSet();
    DataTable DT0;        
    string gender;
private void Filter()
{
     ViewG.DataSource = null;
     ViewG.Rows.Clear();
     command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE s1q2 = @gender";
     command.Parameters.Add("@gender", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
     command.Parameters["@gender"].Value = gender;
     DT0 = DS0.Tables.Add("1Filter");
     mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, connection);

     connection.Open();
     mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
     mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS0.Tables["1Filter"]);
     ViewG.DataSource = DS0.Tables["1Filter"];
     connection.Close();   
}
```

Initially, on the start it retrieves all information from the database code (`SELECT * FROM table`) and displays on the `DataGridView`. And it works fine, but when I try to use filters to retrieve only for example "Females" problem occurs.

For full data I use:

```
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS0.Tables["Full"]);
ViewG.DataSource = DS0.Tables["Full"];
```

For Filtered data:

```
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS0.Tables["1Filter"]);
ViewG.DataSource = DS0.Tables["1Filter"];
```

If I run query used for filter on the application startup it does not duplicate and show correctly.

> EDIT: SOLVED

Comment: Did you check the whether the table itself is having duplicates?

Comment: I checked it does not have any

Comment: it was temp table which had duplicates....

Answer (score 0):

From the code posted here, gender string is not assigned any value. So, your query be applying any filter that you want.

Comment: it is assigned, problems is different

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you effort I found where the problem was. I used temp table on MySql and for some reason server did not dropped this table after connection is closed. So on the new query it added same items on the same table....